# Python: Call Class Function from File up One Level

Tags: python, class

I have a global class called `Global` in the below structure.

```
root_dir
   Global.py
   scripts_dir
      test.py
```

**Global.py**

```
class Global:
    def Test(self):
        return 'test'
```

**test.py**

```
from Global import Global

globalObj = Global()
print(str(globalObj.Test()))
```

**Error**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Global'
```

I'm unable to call the class functions from `Test.py`, I've tried using `import .. Global from Global` with no luck as well.

Comment: Its not the correct syntax. `from Global import Global` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Do not post answers as comments.  Post them as answers.  You get rewarded.

Comment: @MrPyCharm, thanks for that, typo on my part, I already have this correct syntax but it can't find Global class.

Comment: @AdamBarnes That was not actually the answer. The question had a syntactical error in the earlier version. Just pointed that out.

Comment: Right you are, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With folder structure as:

```
root_dir
   Global.py
   scripts_dir
      test.py
```

You have at least two options:

1. You run `python -m scripts_dir.test` from `root_dir`. You will need `__init__.py` file in it so `scripts_dir` becomes Python package though.

Example folder structure:

```
root_dir
   Global.py
   scripts_dir
      __init__.py
      test.py
```

2. You use `python test.py` from `scripts_dir` and inside before importing you use `sys.path.insert` to insert full path to `root_dir`.

Example of using `sys.path`:

```
import os
import sys

ROOT_DIR = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, ROOT_DIR)

from Global import Global

globalObj = Global()
print(str(globalObj.Test()))
```

Comment: I've tried the `sys.path`, no difference, same error. `sys.path.insert(0, PARAMS[3] + '\root_dir\\')
    from Global import Global
    globalClass = Global()`

Comment: I'm not sure what is the value of the path you insert in `sys.path` list. I have updated the example so you have `ROOT_DIR` automatically set based on the position of `test.py` script.